# Guidelines to design rectangular buttons for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

What are the guidelines to design rectangular buttons for IOS? What are the sizes supported by iOS for designing a rectangular button? For eg, the icons are suppose to be of 44X44 pixels, But I was not able to find same for Buttons. Can anyone give me any related link or reference?

Comment: You can make a button of class `UIButton` any size you want through Interface Builder or in code.

Comment: Ther is no fixed size for UIButoon's. It depends on your requirement

Comment: I hope you know you can make button of size 0,0 too through code and IB too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the **[Apple UI Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/)**, It is recommended that you follow button size which is easy to tap by user.

> Create controls that measure at least 44 points x 44 points
>   so they can be accurately tapped with a finger.

However there is no description about maximum button size but it should be appropriate with the content.

[image]

And from iOS **[Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/)**, it says that:

> Embrace borderless buttons. By default, all bar buttons are borderless. In content areas, a borderless button uses context, color, and a call-to-action title to indicate interactivity. And when it makes sense, a content-area button can display a thin border or tinted background that makes it distinctive.

Also look at the **[System Button Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW10)**

A system button:

- Has no border or background appearance by default
- Can contain an icon or a text title
- Supports custom decoration, such as a border or background image (to add a custom appearance, use a button of type UIButtonTypeCustom and supply a custom background image)

Use a system button to initiate an action. When you supply a title for a system button, follow this approach:

- **Use a verb or verb phrase to describe the action the button performs.** An action-specific title shows users that the button is interactive and tells them what will happen when they tap it.
- **Use title-style capitalization.** Capitalize every word except articles, coordinating conjunctions, and prepositions of four or fewer letters.
- **Avoid creating a title that is too long.** Overly long text gets truncated, which can make it difficult for users to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select your button and set it to `UIBUttonTypeCustom` from the interface build, the button can take any shape you want as per your design UI, there is no fixed sizes defined for the buttons